# How to split string to my favorite form in python？

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string which is converted from a list like this：

```
"['station38', 'station28', 'station27', 'station1', 'station0']"
```

I want to split it by comma and become this：

```
list_str=['station38', 'station28', 'station27', 'station1', 'station0']
```

However I can only get this:

```
>>> line_stations = upstream_str.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
["'station38'", "'station28'", "'station27'", "'station1'", "'station0'"]
```

And I have used `strip('"')`, however it failed.

So how to get my favorite form? Thank for your reply.

Comment: Are you trying to process a fragment of a JSON string?

Comment: @DanielHao Use of `eval()` is discouraged as it poses security risks with little upside. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698).

Comment: @stelioslogothetis  Thanks for the reminder.  I knew it - just throw out as an idea... Prob. should give a *Warning* first.

Comment: @DanielHao Of course, just mentioning it because newer Python users might see it and use it unaware of the risks

Comment: *literal_eval()* from the *ast* module is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! The quote you want to get rid of isn't `"`, but `'`. You can use `replace` as before:

```
upstream_str.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", "").split(',')
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) removes a matching character that is at either end of the string. In your case that doesn't work, because before doing `split(",")` the string is:

```
"'station38', 'station28', 'station27', 'station1', 'station0'"
```

Notice that the `'` are all over the middle of the string before you split it into a list. `strip` is useful however, for removing the `[]`:

```
upstream_str.strip('[]').replace("'", "").split(',')
```

You can also look at evaluating the string directly to recover the original list in one operation. I advise looking at the StackOverflow thread on [`literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698).

Comment: You could replace the `.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')` with `.strip('[]')`.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks! Didn't realise

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using a ready-made solution, in this case `ast.literal_eval`.

```py
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("['station38', 'station28', 'station27', 'station1', 'station0']")
['station38', 'station28', 'station27', 'station1', 'station0']
```

That is because there could be all kinds of cases that an ad-hoc solution probably doesn't cover, e.g., something like `"station42'"`.